# На маке не работает шрифты в полях

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, шрифты

Свой шрифт почему-то не работает именно в полях (хром) на маке

Кто уже сталкивался с таким? Как исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В девелопер тулс справа есть закладка (Computed) посмотрите что там пишут о шрифте, может что-то его перепивывает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для каждого браузера лучше использовать свой формат шрифтов:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Если у тебя исходный шрифт в формате `otf` или `eot`, используй конвертер.
Рекомендую: https://everythingfonts.com